# loading jquery validation using requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am struggling with [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/). I have following jquery validation custom addon module defined:

**validation-addon.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'jquery.validate', 'jquery.validate.unobtrusive'], 

function ($) {

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    });

    ....
});
```

My requirejs config file :

**config.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/Scripts',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery-2.0.3',
        'jquery.validate': 'lib/jquery.validate',
        'jquery.validate.unobtrusive': 'lib/jquery.validate.unobtrusive',
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery.validate': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'jquery.validate.unobtrusive': {
            deps: ['jquery.validate']
        }
    }
});
```

I am using these modules on my mvc user regitration view like this:

**register.cshtml**

```
require(['/Scripts/modules/config.js'], function () {
    require(['modules/user-register', 'modules/validation-addon'], 

     function (userregistration) {
        //using user registration module here..
    }

  );
});
```

The problem i am facing is little weird. When i go to user registration view **first time** and input wrong values in use input fields than custom *highlight and unhighlight* functions which i have overridden on jquery validator is not executing but if i reload the register view itself than it suddenly start executing.

My feeling is that may be this is happening because of the loading sequence of modules, but i dont understand how to solve this, can anybody please help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: I assume since you are not using the optimizer ( r.js only possible in node js ) in your .net project. You should name your modules. define('modulename',['dep1','dep2'],function(d1,d2){...});

Comment: @KyorCode but my other modules are working properly and BTW from requirejs documentation `It is normally best to avoid coding in a name for the module and just let the optimization tool burn in the module names.`, but now i am little bit confused, if i am not using r.js (optimization tool) and also not defining the name to the modules than how other modules are working properly except the above mention problem ??

Comment: @gaurav ignore KyorCode's suggestion. It has **nothing** to do with the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a timing issue. These kinds of issue sometimes clear when you do a reload because the order in which things initialize depends on what is in the cache, etc.

It is possible right now that `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` does its work on the DOM *before* the code that calls `$.validator.setDefaults` is executed. To check whether `$.validator.setDefaults` is executed before `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`, remove the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` requirement from `validation-addon.js` and add it to your main file.

Change `validation-addon.js` to:

```
define(['jquery', 'jquery.validate'], 

function ($) {

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    });

    ....
});
```

And change `register.cshtml` to:

```
require(['/Scripts/modules/config.js'], function () {
    require(['modules/user-register', 'modules/validation-addon', 'jquery.validate.unobtrusive'], 

     function (userregistration) {
        //using user registration module here..
    }

  );
});
```

If this solves your problem you probably don't want to keep the code like this but this is a quick and easy way to check whether this is the issue.

Comment: actually i am not manually calling validate method on fields, i used data-* attributes in input elements (tags) which further automatically call validate if user enter wrong value in the input field.

Comment: yes it is `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` that does this work. It reads the data-* attrubutes and attach the appropriate handler with the field and can you please explicitly mention which part of the code you want to see ??

Comment: It is there from the start, actually i am using MVC html helper methods for generating fields, so these helper methods automatically added appropriate data-* according to the dataannotations defined on the model property at server side, and views get compiled at server and html string is return from the server which get display on browser

Comment: Updated answer with the last timing issue I can think of. (BTW, I've started deleting some of my comments on this answer to remove stuff that is no longer useful.)

Comment: great Louis your thinking was perfect it solved my problem, thanks!